# Force TLS > 1.0 on AppEngine local development server in Java

Tags: java, google-app-engine

we need to connect to an external service using at least TLS 1.1, which doesn't work on the local development server using the Java SDK v. 1.9.32. Is there a way to force the local dev server to use a specific version of TLS? Or is it just not supported in the Java SDK?

Comment: What is your local dev server? Tomcat? Jboss?

Answer (score 1):

My local Appengine development server started to use TLS 1.2 once I installed JDK 8 (before I was using JDK 7). [JDK 8 uses TLS 1.2 by default](https://blogs.oracle.com/java-platform-group/entry/java_8_will_use_tls).

Answer (score 1):

Adding to the above answer, since TLS 1.1 and 1.2 are disabled by default on JDK 7, if you don't want to use JDK 8 you can also try modifying the last line of dev_appserver.sh with the following flags:

```
exec "${RUN_JAVA}" "${SCRIPT_NAME}" \
    -Ddeployment.security.TLSv1.1=true -Ddeployment.security.TLSv1.2=true -ea -cp "${JAR_FILE}" \
    com.google.appengine.tools.KickStart \
    com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerMain "$@"
```

Or dev_appserver.cmd on Windows:

```
java -Ddeployment.security.TLSv1.1=true -Ddeployment.security.TLSv1.2=true -cp "%~dp0\..\lib\appengine-tools-api.jar" ^
    com.google.appengine.tools.KickStart ^
    com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerMain %*
```

Comment: I am making the suggested changes to `dev_appserver.sh` in .m2 folder. But, still it is not working for me :(

Comment: I made the changes to the appengine.jvmFlags list in my build.gradle file. It also didn't work for me. :(