# Force TLS 1.2 on appengine dev server SDK

Tags: google-app-engine, braintree, tls1.2

This is similar to this question: [Force TLS > 1.0 on AppEngine local development server in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35878293/force-tls-1-0-on-appengine-local-development-server-in-java) except that the answer doesn't work because it assumes a static SDK location(?).

I have a Google App Engine application that uses a third party payment library (braintree) that communicates over HTTPS using TLSv1.2. However, whenever the braintree library makes calls to the braintree sandbox environment the resulting `urlfetch` always gives the following error:

```
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Could not verify SSL certificate for URL: https://api.sandbox.braintreegateway.com:443/merchants/**********/client_token
    at com.google.appengine.api.urlfetch.URLFetchServiceImpl.convertApplicationException(URLFetchServiceImpl.java:174)
    at com.google.appengine.api.urlfetch.URLFetchServiceImpl.fetch(URLFetchServiceImpl.java:43)
    at com.google.apphosting.utils.security.urlfetch.URLFetchServiceStreamHandler$Connection.fetchResponse(URLFetchServiceStreamHandler.java:543)
    at com.google.apphosting.utils.security.urlfetch.URLFetchServiceStreamHandler$Connection.getInputStream(URLFetchServiceStreamHandler.java:422)
    at com.google.apphosting.utils.security.urlfetch.URLFetchServiceStreamHandler$Connection.getResponseCode(URLFetchServiceStreamHandler.java:275)
    at com.braintreegateway.util.Http.httpRequest(Http.java:120)
```

Whilst this error only happens on the App Engine development server (and not when deployed into App Engine land), it still means that I can't test the stuff I need to in development.

According to this: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-appengine-stackoverflow/tdr4T1CJRn8 the problem is that App Engine isn't using TLSv1.2.

My application is an App Engine app (Standard Environment) using the SDK version 1.9.26.

The `appengine` section of my gradle configuration looks like so:

```
appengine {
    httpAddress = "0.0.0.0"
    httpPort = 8888
    downloadSdk = false

    appcfg {
        update {
            useJava7 = true
        }

        jvmFlags = ['-Ddatastore.backing_store=../../src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/appengine-generated/local_db.bin',
                    // Desperation:
                    '-Ddeployment.security.TLSv1.0=false',
                    '-Ddeployment.security.TLSv1.1=false',
                    '-Ddeployment.security.TLSv1.2=true',
                    '-Dhttps.protocols=TLSv1.2',
                    '-Dappengine.fullscan.seconds=5',
                    '-Xdebug',
                    '-Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=8889',
                    '-XX:MaxPermSize=512m']
        oauth2 = true
        extraOptions = appCfgOpts
    }

    enhancer {
        api = "jdo"
        version = "v1"
        enhanceOnBuild = true
    }

}
```

I have tried updating the dev_appserver.sh in my local appengine-sdk directory to read:

```
exec "${RUN_JAVA}" "${SCRIPT_NAME}" \
    -Dhttps.protocols=TLSv1.2 -Ddeployment.security.TLSv1.0=false -Ddeployment.security.TLSv1.1=false -Ddeployment.security.TLSv1.2=true -ea -cp "${JAR_FILE}" \
    com.google.appengine.tools.KickStart \
    com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerMain "$@"
```

and setting `downloadSdk = false` and setting the `appengine.sdk.root` so that the gradle `appengineRun` task actually uses it.

I cannot use Java 8.
I have also tried putting this in my code:
`System.setProperty("https.protocols", "TLSv1.2");`

None of this works. Either I'm barking up the wrong tree, and trying all the wrong things, or I'm doing something wrong.

How can I get this to work?

**Update:**

It looks like the problem is actually that the sslSocketFactory is never created, because urlfetch will never return an `HttpsURLConnection` ([App Engine URLfetch to validate self-signed certificate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33219930/app-engine-urlfetch-to-validate-self-signed-certificate))

Still searching for a resolution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fix this I had to run the project locally under the Java 8 SDK. Even though Java 8 isn't supported on App Engine yet, at least I can make Braintree sandbox payments in development and actually test my workflow.

I can then rely on the build server to check it still builds under Java 7.

To do this in IntelliJ:

`⌘`+`;` to bring up Project Settings, then change the Project SDK to Java 1.8:
[image: Project Settings]

`⌘`+`,` to bring up Preferences, then change the Gradle JVM option to `Use Project JDK`:
[image: Preferences]

Then run `gradle clean build`. Then run the `appengineRun` gradle task to start up the dev system and all should be fine.

As mentioned in the second answer here: [Force TLS > 1.0 on AppEngine local development server in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35878293/force-tls-1-0-on-appengine-local-development-server-in-java) Java 8 uses TLSv1.8 by default.

Even though it feels totally wrong developing and testing your app on a JRE other than the one it will actually be run on, needs must. :(